# Need to iterate field values from multiple feature classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class, iteration

I have a dataset with two fields: 1. Day 2. Number
I need to filter the first by the number and create feature classes based on that number as they name etc. I have successfully done this with iterate field values. But, I am trying to add a submodel (or at least create another) that will do the same thing to multiple feature classes that were created to generate feature classes by the day. So, my goal is to filter by number, create FCs for those and then filter those FCs by Day. The image below works, but stops after filtering only one of the FCs created by Number. Any ideas on how to filter these in modelbuilder? [image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only have one iterating loop in model builder. If you need two loops, I am afraid that you will need to use Python. You can export your model as a Python script and add the loop above it.

Comment: Do you have a working example of code for this?